# Request for establishing a new privilege: to undo a ban

Tags: feature-request, suspensions

As recent events showed, there is a need for a mechanism that allows a ban of a very active community member to be reversed if it is deemed important by enough community members

In a comment to https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2716/7924, bmike asked me:

*I'm asking for where you'd draw the line when someone repeatedly and vocally attacks another person (clearly making it about them and not their actions). Also - I'm not saying you are wrong until I hear what you propose. I'd like to know where you would draw the line. Do you vote on who gets to ignore the rules? Do you set it at a certain reputation? Do you give someone a free shot at a different person for each 1k reputation? Make a proposal we can debate if you'd like to change the rules.*

Here my request (slightly modified compared to my reply there):

It should be possible to undo a ban upon the intervention of 5 users with enough reputation to merit the privilege of reversing a ban. This could for example taken to be at the level of 250 reps where one earns the privilege of voting to close, or at 2000 reps where one also earns the privilege to vote on edits; any other threshold would be ok, too.

Alternatively, the ban should be undone if 5 people pay a ransom of perhaps 500 reps (or any other reasonable amount, perhaps an amount proportional to the banning time) to show that they are serious about the need to have someone back. This would mean that the sin has been paid for, so justice has been done, as in ordinary life. If less ransom comes in, the ban time should be shortened according to the fraction received.

Comment: I agree with Arnold. Viewpoint of community members should of course be respected.

Comment: Thanks Arnold for fromulating your reasonable suggestions in this questions, wise decision to post it here and NOT on the stack overflow meta ... However, be prepared that the same will happen to your post as did to mine: it will be flooded by random non physics people who come here to downvote this question and any postitive answer and upvote everything rejecting and disagreeing with what you have written.

Comment: If you're posting this here, then I take it as you mean it for PSE only: what is the rational for making PSE an exception? If you don't want it to be an exception, then it should be on MSO.

Comment: I agree with you. It is a reasonable proposal because we have all seen people who should be banned for the good of the community, but there should be a leniency clause for the community.

Comment: @Alenanno It's perfectly fine to initially voice a more global request first at a local level. It can be elevated to a global evaluation after determination of the local thoughts on the matter, or just handled if it makes enough sense from just the local opinion.

Comment: @GraceNote Ah you're right, I forgot about that. :P

Comment: @Alenanno on MSO they will close Arnolds question in a minute and downvote it to -60 in the course of an hour ... :-/. It would be enough if Physics SE could get this additional feature.

Comment: Can the non physicist people who do neither care about our site nor about our community PLEASE STOP DOWNVOTING Arnolds question and more generally STOP COUNTERVOTING the opinion of our community? This feature request concerns only our site and therefore only members of physics SE. Your behaviour is really kindergarten and very destructive ...

Comment: @Dilaton You don't know who is casting what votes. You simply don't. Do you really think the least hypothesis is that people who don't bother with Physics.SE are hanging around here waiting to cast votes you don't like?

Comment: @Alenanno: I post it here because it is needed _at_least_ for PSE. If it is wanted elsewhere, this is fine but not of immediate concern to me.

Comment: @Dilaton - you need 125 reputation to be able to cast a down-vote even on a meta. That means that you *have* to earn some reputation on the site in order to do that. The 100 point association bonus isn't enough. So anyone casting a down-vote **is** a user of Physics and hence part of the community.

Comment: @dmckee Anna v noticed this independent from me too; it is obvious and Shog9 almost admitted it, please have a look at the corresponding discussion somewhere in the discussion between him and Anna below my latest meta question. It is obvious from the huge number users suddenly commenting and answering here who have no or an almost negligible amount of rep on Physics SE and did not participate in any constructive way in our community before.

Comment: What you both noticed is that *not everybody agrees with you*. Neither of your--nor me for that matter--know who those people are or how much time they spend on Physics.SE.

Comment: @ChrisF ok by countervoting I mean upvoting what people who dont care about our site and our community too; this is not less bad than the downvotes. What about mods form other sides? Are they able to downvote everywhere?

Comment: @Dilaton No, mods have extra powers in their own site and chat only. In the rest of the network they're normal users.

Comment: Prof. Neumaier, I upvoted your proposal because it is sympathetic to my own values. However, while it would surely be a net plus for Questioners on physics.SE to have Ron return and resume providing useful Answers (except when on the topic of cold fusion, hehe), I believe it could be a mistake for him personally. A place like stackexchange, or wikipedia, or the church of scientology, can quickly become an absorbing experience to the detriment of more important matters in one's life. I suspect that he provoked his suspension in an attempt to rip himself free of the tentacles binding him.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel: One doesn't need a forced suspension to quit temporarily from a site. And an addict wouldn't ruin voluntarily his venue of addiction.

Comment: This has little bearing on the current discussion, @Arnold, but... I have seen more than one person request a suspension voluntarily due to realizing they were unable to balance their time on the site with other responsibilities...

Comment: @Shog9: If Ron would have asked for suspension, I wouldn't want to lift the ban.

Comment: @Arnold: if he'd asked for it explicitly, I wouldn't have given it (I generally suggest other ways of temporarily revoking your own access). I think what Eugene is suggesting here is something vaguely akin to [suicide by cop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suicide_by_cop) - I don't really buy into that theory however; it does not seem quite in keeping with what I've seen of Ron's philosophy.

Comment: I like Arnold Neumaier's proposal very much.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93806/is-there-going-to-be-a-process-around-hellbanning

Answer (score 29):

With all of the other vote-controlled mechanisms on SE, you have every bit of information you need to vote. For example, wrt closing and reopening, you can see the post and all the comments. You're not making a blind decision.

In this case, the suspension details (the warnings, the exact offence, etc) are private and only viewable by moderators (and the suspended party). Due to the [moderator agreement](https://physics.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement), this information cannot be released by the moderators.

Without full knowledge of the situation, an un-ban would be a blind decision. Moderators are [human exception handlers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), they're the ones meant to deal with this. And they already have. There is no point (IMO) asking them to undo this, the ban was enacted by a community team member (according to Ron), and it was regarding network policy--upheld by the moderators.

Comment: But this bruhaha happened on meta.Physics.SE, let the ban hold for meta>Physics.SE since it in no way represents the physics.SE community as it so amply has been displayed for all to see. It is a free for all for all moderators of SE. The community will not care if he/she is banned on meta as long as the behavior has not appeared in the physics community.

Comment: @annav - unfortunately some of the behaviour did spill over to the main site.

Comment: @ChrisF as for example?

Comment: @annav - Basically, Ron defaced some of his own posts. Vandalism - even self vandalism - is not allowed anywhere on the network.

Comment: @ChrisF  what???? give a link

Comment: @annav - that wouldn't be wise. However, I'm sure you can find them if you look hard enough. Unless you mean a link stating that self vandalism isn't allowed.

Comment: @annav, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/45672/revisions for one specific example. For all of them, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Sorry @ChrisF, my comment crossed with yours. But I don't see why that would be a problem; that information is available to any person on the internet.

Comment: @annav Yes, Ron put political commentary at the top of (at least one of) his regular physics answers, a very silly thing to do.

Comment: @Eugene May be Ron knew that posting his request on meta was of no use. And now its almost clear that he was right. We already have so many people governing our physics site who have actually nothing to do with physics.

Comment: The rules on SE seem to be much worse than that in real life, where only the worst offences cannot be challenged before a court, and where offences of etiquette can _always_ be redeemed by paying something in the accepted currency. One doesn't have to know everything about the law or the particular incident to do that.

Comment: If privacy were the main reason for not creating the requested privilege, one could easily change the moderator agreement to lift the privacy. In ordinary life, courts are also open to everyone in  most topics where public rules are broken.

Comment: @dushya: I strongly urge you to take a look at the activity history of both your three current elected moderators and the candidates in this current election. I suspect you do not realize just how much work they put in here. Everyone loves to complain about moderator actions when they blow up, without bothering to note all of the little fires they put out *before* they spread.

Comment: @Shog9 Did i use term "moderator" ? If requests of reputable community members are not being heard, then i suspect the people who are truly in command of site do not really care for physics.

Comment: @ColinMcFaul I never saw those flags so ofcourse they did not bother me. I do not call them vandalism since it was in his own answer. Vandalism is against other people. It is a political statement and he obviously felt strongly about this and wanted to alert the community. I do not know how I would have reacted had I seen the series.

Comment: @ChrisF 1.If community members find something "wrong" in someone's answer they always have a downvote option available. If moderator's find that the answer is being downvoted by members then they can edit it or may be delete it. But in any case his comment was not as serious as to suspend him for one month. 2.If (as Anna said) reason to suspend him was his bad behavior on MetaPhys then he should have been suspended as a meta user not as a physics user 3. If you still think it was right to suspend him for his behaviour then why the other guy was not suspended who too used bad words for him.

Comment: @dushya: (1) It was a conglomeration of many offences in the past two days. Defacing his posts on main, disrupting meta by posting effectively the same thing over and over again, and disrupting a chat session. The entire bundle _is_ a serious offence. (3) The "other guy" didn't say "bad words" about him. Or if he did, he only did so once (though the link to the crackpot site seems more like an ill-timed joke). Ron did so _repeatedly_, even after repeated warnings. Clear difference here.

Comment: @Manishearth .. but still why one month ? Don't you think its a big loss to the site; much bigger than the loss that his behaviour might have caused ?

Comment: @dushya: He had already been suspended once. Standard policy is to increase the duration of subsequent suspensions for offences of the same degree. Not much you can do about that.

Comment: @Manishearth: Not much you can do about that now, according to the rules. This is why we urgently need the new privilege.

Comment: The nice thing about rules is that they can be changed if there are strong reasons for changing them. They are not immutable scientific laws.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier you are right, but we should either discuss the laws or Ron's case. Ron has been handled fairly within the current context and expectations - context and expectations that Ron knew perfectly well.

Comment: Have you ever asked yourself why Ron *chose* to behave like this? Do you think he didn't *know* he was going to be suspended? Of course he knew! He's been suspended plenty of times, here and on other sites... IMO he deliberately provoked his own suspension in order to provoke the strongest possible reaction during election. *This* is what I mean when I say he's disruptive and damaging to the community.

Comment: @Sklivvz: If the rules are unjust (strong mismatch between offence and punishment, and hitting the site more than the person), then fair handling of the rules count for nothing.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier ...except he *knew* he would be suspended for a month. *Exactly* the same thing happened to him on another site.

Comment: Here we discuss changing the rules.

Comment: @Arnold: here's perhaps a lesser-known tidbit about the *length* of suspensions: it's mostly irrelevant. The original expectation was that accounts would be *deleted* after the first suspension if the problem wasn't corrected, but that was later dropped in favor of increasingly-lenthy periods. A message is sent along with every suspension, and a private channel visible only to moderators and staff provided for the suspended member to respond. If the moderator and suspended member can come to a resolution, the suspension can be lifted at any time... Sadly, this does not often happen.

Comment: @Shog9: If the length is mostly irrelevant, why has it been chosen in Ron's case to be a month rather than to the end of the electrion (which would have made sense from the context)? See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2758/7924

Comment: The problem was not the election.

Comment: @Shog9: Ron became offensive to the point of being suspended only because of a candidate in the election.

Comment: Anyway, I now understand the way this site is governed. I decided that I don't want to continue to nurture a site that values strict rules over the subject matter, and imposes unduly draconic punishments http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_%28lawgiver%29 on unsubmissive but valuable people. I will use it in future just as a potential source rather than a place to spend my time. It will free me at least 15 hours a week that I can invest in a more science-friendly environment.

Comment: @Arnold: I think it's always important to use the right tool for the right job. If, for instance, one cannot keep their composure in an environment that allows others with whom they disagree to enter, a mailing list is probably the better tool. I like the Stack Exchange system, but it is not the be-all and end-all of Internet communication.

Comment: @Shog9: I understand that, and I don't want to quarrel, but measures should be adequate to the situation. I tried to pave the way for a constructive compromise, but I lost the faith that it would be implemented.

Comment: There's really only one person who can agree to a compromise in this situation, @Arnold.

Comment: @Shog9 yep you are this person who could have agreed to a compromise to resolve the issue. But you obviously never agree on any compromise. This must make you very successful and strong in the "real live" .

Comment: You sound bitter, @Dilaton. I recommend a nice cup of tea. Then, if you have a constructive suggestion or complaint to make, I'm easy to get in touch with.

Answer (score 18):

Suspensions are private, and in some cases like vote fraud most of the details have to remain private at all times. The users voting to undo a suspension don't have access to all the information about the incident, how are they supposed to make a reasoned judgement without knowing what exactly happened?

When a user is suspended, a lot of the information that is based on is not available to regular users. This are e.g. deleted posts (which are available, but you can't find them easily), deleted comments, annotations about previous behaviour and information related to the vote fraud and sock puppet detection tools. You need all this information to judge whether the suspension is warranted, and most of this information can't be made public.

Comment: No the only thing that counts to decide if the ban should be undone is the importance of the user to the local community. It is only about being able to contriute to the LOCAL site so undoing the ban should be the business and judgement of the local community and its mods alone.

Comment: Users have all the details needed to judge that a member is essential for the community. This should be enough to redeeem a member when it fell into disfavor at superior instances.

Comment: Does anyone know why suspensions are private?? I mean shouldn't it bother the user of a SE site to know what made a person pariah? A citizen has every right to know who did what and how to avoid it!!

Comment: @VineetMenon: The rules of the site are all public. Read them, you shall know how to avoid it.

Comment: Suspensions are private to avoid sticking someone with The Mark of Cain for a mistake they've later corrected, @Vineet. Of course, well-meaning colleagues repeatedly bringing it up in public sorta works against this, but...

Comment: @Shog9: Then the reasons for the mark of Cain should be removed after the suspension is over, but not during suspension where the mark of Cain is very visibly imposed anyway

Comment: @Arnold: that is indeed how it works for the effects shown on the profile page. Removing all auxiliary discussion is not so easily done (moderators will tend to remove unconstructive or obsolete discussions over time, but ideally folks would be encouraged to participate in more general, constructive discussion of policy that can inform and guide others in the future instead).

Answer (score 10):

Bans and suspensions need to be carried out by moderators.

There's no correlation between someone's ability to answer/ask physics questions and their social intelligence. Moderators, on the other hand, are usually judged by a community over a long period of time as possessing a character which enables them to consistently deal with people in a calm, fair and detached manner.

There is nothing stopping a person on the receiving end of abuse to appeal for the suspension to be lifted or reduced using the meta page anyway.

Comment: When a person is suspended, they can't post on meta either. Their recourse is to appeal to the moderators by responding to the message that's always sent along with the suspension or contacting us (the Stack Exchange team) by email.

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid the problem that voting users don’t know why a person was banned, I would suggest giving the banned user a possibility to ‘Appeal to Community’, which would make the details of the ban public (at least to the users eligible to vote on the appeal).

One could take this a little further by first requiring one of these users to vouch for the banned person and then giving the banned person a choice to appeal publicly, appeal without making details public or not appeal.

I would suggest the reputation threshold required to vote on such appeals to be at least 2k.

Comment: Aah thanks Claudius, this is a really helpful and constructive answer +1

Comment: So you think there's a link between someone's knowledge of physics and their social intelligence?

Comment: No, but there is a strong correlation between someone answering/asking many good questions (i.e. the work they put in PSE) and their good-will regarding the community. Someone who himself spent a long time here will be very careful not to let someone he perceives as a threat to the community come back and has a genuine interest in keeping such people at bay.